# Am I interpreting this correctly? 凡物只所持，不外乎三种，神念、灵气、元血。只是，一旦错了。就不知会如何了。

Tags: translation, meaning-in-context

I'm reading a web novel called "凤凰仙尊，刁妻萌娃好难训." There's a sentence which confused me, so I hope someone could tell me if my interpretation's already correct.

> 凡物只所持，不外乎三种，神念、灵气、元血。只是，一旦错了。就不知会如何了。

I assumed the meaning is

> There are only three kinds of things to be controlled: divine comprehension, spiritual aura, and primordial blood. But (we) don't know what'd happen if a mistake occurs.

Comment: You probably mean 凡物**之**所持，不外乎三种，神念、灵气、元血。只是，一旦错了，就不知会如何了，it should be 之 instead of 只。

Comment: @zyy Is that a typo then? I copied the sentence from the novel...

Comment: @Fai91 It should be a typo, 只 does not make sense in this sentence.

Comment: @zyy So is my interpretation correct?

Comment: @Fai91 It is hard to translate such terms to English, plus they themselves are some made up concepts. But anyway, 神念 should mean comprehension of the world, 灵气 should mean spiritual realization, 元血 should be referring to the flesh of a person.

Comment: @zyy actually, my problem is the early part of the sentence: "凡物只所持，不外乎三种". Is "There are only three kinds of things to be controlled" correct?

Comment: @Fai91 Your interpretation is correct! You only need to realize that 持 here can mean "possess thus is able to control".

Comment: I am not a native speaker myself, but i I were to translate it, my translation would be close to yours.

Answer (score 1):

凡物只所持，不外乎三种，神念、灵气、元血。只是，一旦错了。就不知会如何了。

In my opinion,i translate to `凡是万物若想要控置他们，不外乎三个，神圣意念，灵魂气息，元血。只是，其中一個一旦错了。就不知会如何了。`

If all things want to control them, there are only three kinds of things to be controlled
: divine ideology, spiritual aura, and primordial blood. But (we) don't know what'd happen if a mistake(at least one of three concept is in incomprehension) occurs.

神念 means the mindset of the thing(or person,creature).

灵气 means the fourth dimension of the thing.

元血 is the medium to communicate to the third dimension of physical body.

reference by myself

Answer (score 0):

For reference consult Baidu: just enter: XYZ是什么意思 see what comes up!

It’s a kind of magic!

神识是精神力的一种，一些法术和法器要神识才能用，也可以用来‘看’东西，比如隔着墙、隔着山。神识还可以用来攻击威力很大，神识还有专其他作用，比如：脑出血，神识可以无损的把血逼出来，不过技术要求太高。神识也可以‘看’到精神组属织，做手术可以避开精神组织这个要求不高。 补充： 神识是修士的眼睛。神念是神的眼睛。神祗就是神。

The author of the above may be muddling 神 and 神奇;神异 [magic]

神识是精神力的一种
Divine knowledge is a kind of spiritual strength

神念: 神念是神的眼睛。
divine compassion: that is gods eyes

灵气、：神话中的超自然的力量；神奇的能力。
spiritual power: In legend supranatural strength; magical power

元血: “九州遍洒黎元血”的意思是中国大地上到处都洒满民众的鲜血。
original blood: "(In the) 9 states everywhere spread Li ethnic group original blood" the meaning is, in China's mainland everywhere spread (Li) people's blood.

To your sentence, my spin:

凡物只所持，不外乎三种，
Only three forces maintain ordinary things,

神念、
divine compassion,

灵气、
spiritual power

元血。
original blood.

只是，一旦错了。就不知会如何了。
but, if something goes pear-shaped, well, not sure what'll happen.

We might end up with a Prime Minister like Boris, or a President like Donald!